# Is there a simpler way for a password to generate again if password starts with a number?

Tags: python

I am trying to build this really simple "password generator" and I was wondering if there is a simpler way to generate a new password if the password starts with an integer

```
choices = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

randomPass = random.sample(choices, length)

password = "".join(randomPass)
password1 = "".join(randomPass)

#checks password

if password[0].isdigit():
  print("password started with number generating another password...")

  if password1[0].isdigit():
    print("started with a number again, trying again...")

  else:
    print(password1)

else:
  print(password)
```

The way I'm doing this is not efficient at all and no matter how many times I do this there's still a chance I will generate a password with a number at the beginning, but I am sure that using a loop will eliminate the possibility of a number being the first character in the password and will make life a lot easier, I just don't know how, could someone help?

Comment: You could make it a lot simpler if you didn't generate identical strings for `password` and `password1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct fix for your code is a loop:

```
while password[0].isdigit():
    print("password started with number generating another password...")
    password = "".join(random.sample(choices, length))
```

However, better yet is to construct a legal password in the first place: get the first character from letters only:

```
choices = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

first_letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
randomPass = first_letter + ''.join(random.sample(choices, length-1))
```

Comment: You must use `''.join(random.sample(choices, length-1))` when creating `randomPass`.

Comment: I'd recommend `while True: password = "..."; if password[0].isdigit(): break`, to avoid duplicate definitions of `password` inside and outside the loop.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative; I'm well aware of it.  In my experience, it's better to replicate the assignment, and to have the loop logic in the loop header -- not in a conditional, unnatural exit within the loop.  I "grew up" in the era of structured programming.  :-)